# Meaning of address and route scope

Tags: networking, iproute

I've been searching information concerning the meaning of scopes both in addresses and routes but I don't understand the documentation I've read so far. This is what I've been reading:

- man 8 ip
- http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2-toc.html
- http://www.policyrouting.org/PolicyRoutingBook/ONLINE/TOC.html
- Source code of iproute2-4.5.0 (though I've lost familiarity with source code in C, so not much I got from this).

Is there other documentation I could read? Google for "iproute2 address scope" and similar was not helpful. What I thought an address scope would mean was how that address could be reached:

- "host": only from localhost.
- "link": only from other hosts directly attached to the network to which the corresponding device is attached to.
- "global": "host" + "link".
- Other scopes would be reserved for future usage.

I see no change in behavior if I change from "global" to "host", "link" or "3" the scope of the address my laptop is assigned through DHCP and the result was:

- In all cases I could ping from my laptop to that address and to the Internet.
- In all the cases I could ping from a virtual machine on the same laptop using a virtual NIC bridged to the same interface and with a manual network setup to that address.

Note that I'm only using IPv4.

Answer (score 1):

One effect of address scope is to determine when the address will be selected for outgoing connections.  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3484#section-4 (via `man gai.conf`).

Looking at the examples, the first given seems to be that it avoids using a link-local address when contacting a globally unique address.  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3484#section-10.1

To be honest I don't remember finding any other significance of scopes in Linux.  Presumably there was some reason they're available on routes though.  The address selection is a userspace thing, so I expect it's distinct from the routing.

Comment: edit: I stared at the algorithm trying to think of an example.  Eventually I remembered there's actually an example section.  Suggested moral: worked examples make everything better :).

Comment: RFC3484 stands for "Default Address Selection for Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6)" and I'm working on IPv4.

Comment: Scopes are (originally) an IPv6 concept.

Comment: update: actually the RFC says "The destination address selection algorithm operates on both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses.  For this purpose, IPv4 addresses should be represented as IPv4-mapped addresses"

Comment: Exactly, but I'm dealing with the source address.