# What is the difference between Scopes: Host, Local and Global

Tags: linux, networking

I don't seem to understand why when using `ip route` the scope is set to link, but when using `ip address` the scope is set to global.

ip route:

```
192.168.197.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.197.199
```

ip address:

```
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:0c:29:1b:a0:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.197.199/24 brd 192.168.197.255 scope global ens33
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe1b:a07e/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Shouldn't the scope of them both be link because they are only valid addresses on the private network?

Comment: very short tip: link local does not do routing, and "global" does.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276550/117549